# CreateQuery constructor with getting parameter list

Tags: list, constructor, createquery

I'm new here and this is my second question, but as the first, I have a problem already tried to solve in different ways, but have not found a solution, so I'm resorting to you, here we go.

My code:

```
                string sql = "SELECT NEW Filial(fil.NumSequencial, fil.Numero, fil.Nome, fil.Cnpj, fil.Empresa, fil.LstUsuario)" +
                        " FROM Filial fil" +
                        "   join fetch fil.LstUsuario usrFil";

            IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(sql);

            lstFilial = (List<Filial>)query.List<Filial>();
```

I've tried with and without the line "join fetch", but the error is always the same:

> {"illegal syntax near collection: id [SELECT NEW Filial(fil.NumSequencial, fil.Numero, fil.Nome, fil.Cnpj, fil.Empresa, fil.LstUsuario) FROM Leitor_NFe_XML_Entidade.Filial fil\tjoin fetch fil.LstUsuario usrFil]"}

The constructor:

```
public Filial(long numSequencial, int numero, string nome, string cnpj, Empresa empresa, IList<Usuario> lstUsuario)
    {
        this.numSequencial = numSequencial;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.lstUsuario = lstUsuario;
    }
```

Am thankful since already

Comment: An important detail, retreat if the parameter list (lstUsuario), works perfect.

Comment: Man, do not have a question I ask here someone responds.